# Getting two different sets of results for $\sqrt{17+7\sin(2x)}=3\sin(x)+5\cos(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The equation is

$$\sqrt{17+7\sin(2x)}=3\sin(x)+5\cos(x)$$

My solution is, first, to define a system:

$$
\begin{cases}
17+7\sin(2x)=(3\sin(x)+5\cos(x))^2 \\
3\sin(x)+5\cos(x)\ge 0
\end{cases}
$$

Next, simplify the equation:

$$17+14\sin(x)\cos(x)=9\sin^2(x)+30\sin(x)\cos(x)+25\cos^2(x) \iff$$
$$17(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))=9\sin^2(x)+16\sin(x)\cos(x)+25\cos^2(x) \iff$$
$$8\cos^2(x)+16\cos(x)\sin(x)-8\sin^2(x)=0$$
$$(\sqrt8\cos(x)-\sqrt8\sin(x))^2=0$$
$$\cos(x)=\sin(x)$$
$$x_1=\frac \pi 4; x_2=\frac {5\pi} 4$$

Then I peeked into the textbook's answer, and, lo and behold,

$$\color{red}{x_1=-\frac \pi 8 +2\pi n; x_2=\frac {3\pi} 8 + 2\pi n}$$

---

I backtracked my solution and solved the equation using the double-angle identity:

$$8\cos^2(x)+16\cos(x)\sin(x)-8\sin^2(x)=0$$

I used this: $16\cos(x)sin(x)=8\sin(2x); 8\cos^2(x)-8\sin^2(x)=8\cos(2x)$. Substituting this gives us the following:

$$8\sin(2x)=-8\cos(2x)$$
$$2x=-\frac \pi 4; 2x=\frac {3\pi} 4$$ 
Which yields the textbook's result.

But where did I err in my first solution process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

In general,
$$8\cos^2(x)+16\cos(x)\sin(x)-8\sin^2(x)\ne(\sqrt8\cos(x)-\sqrt8\sin(x))^2$$

as $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ which is in general $\ne a^2-2ab-b^2$

Divide both sides of $$8\cos^2(x)+16\cos(x)\sin(x)-8\sin^2(x)=0$$ by $8\cos^2x$

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align*}
&&17(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))&=9\sin^2(x)+16\sin(x)\cos(x)+25\cos^2(x) \\
\iff&& 8\sin^2 (x)-16\sin (x)\cos(x)-8\cos^2(x)&=0
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, indeed. A trivial error. Thank you!